Angular Material - Scrolling issue for select component mat-option
I can't see the scroll or the scroll bar of the options, how can I fix it, I use version 9 of angular.  example
I have tried ng-scroll with version 7.56 but it is not possible due to compatibility issues with the angular 9 project.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
